# Inconsistency with findmeetingtime graph api response

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365, microsoft365

We are using FindMeetingTimes to get Office 365 Rooms resources which are available in a given time constraint.
When number of rooms in Office 365 are less then it is working fine even if multiple hits are made simultaneously.

But eg- If i have 48 rooms and hitting this api simultaneously i'm getting random results instead of getting 48.

Comment: Just to isolate the issue out of your code i would suggest you to replicate the issue with Microsoft Graph Explorer or POSTMAN and see if you can still repro the issue. If yes, please share the related info - so that the community can help.

Comment: Moving this to answer. Consider upvoting it and accept it as answer. So it can be useful to others in the community as well :)

Also if you repro the issue share the related info. So that we can help as well.

Comment: We tried with Postman making multiple batch calls using Graph Batch to Graph API "FindMeetingTime", but getting random results and the entire batch is failing.  Eg- If i created 10 batches with 5 attendees in each request and also tried 10 batches with one attendee only. Still we didn't get all results.  Out of 10 batches atleast 4-5 batches were returning no results with a Success status code 200.

Answer (score 0):

Just to isolate the issue out of your code i would suggest you to replicate the issue with Microsoft Graph Explorer or POSTMAN and see if you can still repro the issue. If yes, please share the related info - so that the community can help.

Comment: We tried with Postman making multiple batch calls using Graph Batch to Graph API "FindMeetingTime", but getting random results and the entire batch is failing. Eg- If i created 10 batches with 5 attendees in each request and also tried 10 batches with one attendee only. Still we didn't get all results. Out of 10 batches atleast 4-5 batches were returning no results with a Success status code 200.

Comment: Interesting... I played using POSTMAN/Graph Explorer with the findmeetingtime API - multiple individual API calls (not the Batch ones) and it returned me the right results. Just see that the issue happens only with batch calls or with individual calls also from your end? This may help you to isolate the issue.

Comment: 1 Failure and Success Response:

Status Code:  200
b'{"@odata.context":"...","emptySuggestionsReason":"Unknown","meetingTimeSuggestions":[]}'
No of Rooms:  0

Status Code:  200
b'{"@odata.context":"...","emptySuggestionsReason":"","meetingTimeSuggestions":[{"confidence":100.0,"organizerAvailability":"free","attendeeAvailability":[{"availability":"free","attendee":{"emailAddress":{"address":"TestRoom2@xyz.com"}}},"meetingTimeSlot":{"start":{"dateTime":"2021-01-28T07:30:00.0000000","timeZone":"UTC"},"end":{"dateTime":"2021-01-28T08:00:00.0000000","timeZone":"UTC"}}}]}'
No of Rooms:  1

Comment: Hmm, above i see that it returns "emptysuggestionsreason" - If findMeetingTimes cannot return any meeting suggestions, the response would indicate a reason in the emptySuggestionsReason property. Based on this value, you can better adjust the parameters and call findMeetingTimes again.  In scenarios like test environments where the input parameters and calendar data remain static, expect that the suggested results may differ over time.